# IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: java, android, file

i read many posts about EBADF but non of them solved my problem .

so what i am doing is converting .jpg format to bytes
and eventually i want to wrtie bytes as binary file.

here is my code.

```
public static void writeBytes(byte[] bytes,String dstPath){
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;

        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(dstPath);
            bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            bout.write(bytes);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            
        } finally {
            try {

                if (fout != null)
                    fout.close();

                if (bout != null)
                    bout.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

the problem occurs when the bout.write(bytes) is called .

Comment: Where is "bytes" defined? Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: Also, did you check dstPath to make sure it's ok?

Comment: dst is ok . and bytes ok too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i find the problem .

buffer size in (BufferedOutputStream) by default is 8192 and my bytes size was less than it . so i change code like bellow.

```
public static void writeBytes(byte[] bytes,String dstPath){
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
        
        int bufferSize = 8192;
        if(bytes.length < bufferSize){
            bufferSize = bytes.length;
        }
        try{
            fout=new FileOutputStream(dstPath);
            bout=new BufferedOutputStream(fout,bufferSize);
            bout.write(bytes);

        }catch (IOException io){
            
        }finally {
            try {
                fout.close();
                bout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

i set the buffer size equals to the size of the bytes by this condition.

```
 int bufferSize = 8192;
        if(bytes.length < bufferSize){
            bufferSize = bytes.length;
        }
```

and set buffer size to BufferedOutputStream

```
bout=new BufferedOutputStream(fout,bufferSize);
```

i'm not sure this is standard way but is working for me.

Comment: Two lines: fout=new FileOutputStream(dstPath); fout.write(bytes); will do. You can remove all code messing around with bufferSize.

Comment: without using BufferedOutputStream  its doesn't effect on write speed ?

Comment: Dont think so.And why dont you test that?  But if you want to use a BufferedoutputStream well ok but dont use the second parameter. No bufferSize parameter. But... if it would become faster with that parameter then do. Just test for yourself.